# Slater's condition in conic programming

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I'm reading some PDF in conic programming. When we define duality and want to know when strong duality holds we use Slater's condition. In some references the cone should be pointed and in other pointedness is not needed. Could you please tell me being pointed for the cone is necessary or not?

Comment: It is possible to relax the pointed condition but it requires great care.

Comment: @MichaelGrant What do you mean? When we can omit pointed condition?

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two relevant remarks:

1. Only pointed cones define a partial order.
2. When a cone is closed, it is pointed if and only if its dual cone has a nonempty interior.

Comment: So it is true that strong duality is true in case when we dont have a pointed cone also? when the primal and dual are feasible and primal has a feasible solution that is in relative interior of the convex cone.

Comment: It is definitely true in some cases. Think of $\min_x \{ c^Tx : Ax=b, x \in K\}$ where $K=\{x : x_1 \geq 0 \}$.